# Creating a batch script to shut down machine after multiple restart or stopping of services

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have created a `batch` script that is able to shut down the machine after multiple restarts or halts of a particular window service.

However, I have no idea about **how to make the script work automatically instead of running it manually**. I have tried testing the script file by setting it up under `services.msc` and setting it to *`run a program (batch file)`* after subsequent failures under this particular window service but when I stopped or restart the service 3 times manually, the batch script did not run at all .

So I'm thinking it could be that `services.msc` only recognizes failures before running the script instead of stopping or restarting the service. If so, is there any other way to run the script?

This is my batch script:

```
sc query "AVG Antivirus" | find "STOPPED" 
    if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3" 
    (
        shutdown.exe /s /t 00
    )
```

Comment: I removed the `bash` tag because the question is not Unix related at all

Answer (score 0):

`%errorlevel%` doesn't "count" - it always gives `0` for "success" and `NOT 0` (usually `1`, but depends on the command). So you have to implement an own counter:

```
set count=0
:loop
  sc query "AVG Antivirus" | find "STOPPED" && set /a count+=1
  if %count% geq 3 goto :continue
  timeout /t 5
goto :loop
:continue
shutdown.exe /s /t 00
```

`||` works as "if previous command (`find` here) failed then" (the opposite is `&&` "if previous command was successful")

I'm not sure if you need the service to be RUNNING or STOPPED. Difference is just using `&&` or `||`)